# Ruby on Rails - Polymorphic Association with Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to implement a `Category` model to my application. I'm trying to design it in a way that `Users` can have many `Categories`, and so can `Groups`.

The problem I'm running into is that I also want to be able to just have a normal list of `Categories` without them being assigned to any `User` or `Group`.

I was referencing [rubyonrails.org/association_basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

```ruby
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.text :description
        t.references :categorizable, polymorphic: true, index: true
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :categorizable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories, :as => :categorizable
end

class Group< ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories, :as => :categorizable
end
```

I'm trying to create a new `Category` through `rails c`, but whenever I try to save, it rolls back my transaction probably because I'm missing some condition.

```bash
Category(id: integer, name: string, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Category.create( :id => 1, :name => 'Category_1', :description => '' )
begin transaction
rollback transaction
```

I also feel like there is a better way to create a new `Category`, as I shouldn't be setting the `id` manually.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you using rails 5?

Comment: If you shouldn't be setting the id, why are you doing that then? Is  `begin transaction` and `rollback transaction` all you can see in the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails 5, whenever you define a `belongs_to` association, it is required to have the associated record present by default. You would see this when you look at the errors after trying to create the category object

```
category = Category.create(:name => 'Category_1', :description => '' )
category.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
```

If you want to be able to save a record without the belongs_to association, you would have to specify it explicitly

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true, required: false
end
```

Comment: I was able to create a Category separate from the Group/Users, but how do I assign a Group to a Category? For example, I create 10 Categories, and allow the group be categorized into those existing Categories, instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. I did `Category.create!(...)`, and then `group.categories << Category.find(4)`. Does that sound correct?

Comment: I realized that I can't have multiple Groups reference the same category. If I assign it to one, it removes the other. How can I make sure that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to create a new category and see the error is that there needs to exists a categorizable record in order for the category to be created, an easy way to do it is to put the new object itself as the categorizable one and it should do the trick.

```bash
$ category = Category.new
=> #<Category id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, categorizable_type:   nil, categorizable_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
$ category.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
$ category.errors.full_messages
=> ["Categorizable must exist"]
$ category = Category.new(categorizable: category)
=> #<Category id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, categorizable_type: "Category", categorizable_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
$ category.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("categorizable_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["categorizable_type", "Category"], ["created_at", 2017-01-15 00:08:55 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-01-15 00:08:55 UTC]]
(0.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help, Rails Cast on Polymorphic
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l9EAuev16k

You can create polymorphic records with this...

```
`@category = @categorizable.User.new`
`@category = @categorizable.Group.new`
```

So you do not need the id.

Comment: I get nil for `@categorizable`.

Comment: Same, seems like this would be a good fix but it doesn't work for me.